# Return value from server class

Tags: java, server, runnable

I need a return value from a server class that looks basicly like this.

I need to return that object while the server keeps running. 
What is the easiest way to accomplish that?

```
Object o = null;

try {
  ServerSocket socketConnection = new ServerSocket(123456);
  while(true)
  {
   Socket pipe = socketConnection.accept();

   ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new
          ObjectInputStream(pipe.getInputStream());


   object = (Object)serverInputStream.readObject();
```

Comment: return where? Do you want your method to be `asynchronous`?

Comment: yes. The (it's actutally kinda homework) task it to build a holiday planner. Holiday requests can be send from different clients (Swing, GWT) to the server. At this point it is used by a class using service methods to prompt the database. I thought that might be done with some Callback method ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that a method return some value and still continue execution. But you can fork a thread and then return the value (When you start a thread it will immediately return the control to the same program). Note that the order of the threads will not be a guarantee.